# Listen when time changes to 00:00 in Android

Tags: android, datetime

What are the techniques available where when time changes to 00:00 (system clock time)?

I should get a trigger, callback, or notification to my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AlarmManager and Broadcast Receiver to achieve that
See the example from the Android Documentation here :
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html